# Symfony3 Tetranz/select2 - remote_route

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the select2entity-bundle for my project to implement auto-complete.

When using the builder, the specification is as follows :

```
$builder
   ->add('country', Select2EntityType::class, [
            'multiple' => true,
            'remote_route' => 'tetranz_test_default_countryquery',
            'class' => '\Tetranz\TestBundle\Entity\Country',
            'primary_key' => 'id',
            'text_property' => 'name',
            'minimum_input_length' => 2,
            'page_limit' => 10,
            'allow_clear' => true,
            'delay' => 250,
            'cache' => true,
            'cache_timeout' => 60000, // if 'cache' is true
            'language' => 'en',
            'placeholder' => 'Select a country',
            // 'object_manager' => $objectManager, // inject a custom object / entity manager 
        ])
```

What should be specified within the 'remote_route' parameter?
Why should my field be linked to a route? How and where should this route be configured? Should it be linked to a query?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select needs to update the values to display while he user is typing. It does this by sending a request to a controller you need to write, which collects the relevant values and returns them as json.

Create a controller that returns the list of items to display in the select, and use the name of the route you defined for that controller as the 'remote_route' parameter.

The format for the returned data is documented halfway down the page for the bundle on github https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle

Comment: Hi Phil, Thank you for your answer. I think something might have been wrong has your answer has not been sent entirely.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I submitted to early and then the edit didn't take. Have updated.